# formulario en jsp con varias acciones

Tags: jsp

Estoy haciendo un formulario en jsp que me deje editar y borrar a la vez, tengo un problema con la opción borrar varios, donde he puesto un checkbox a cada uno para seleccionar los que quieras y borrarlos a la vez. El problema que tengo es que solo puedo poner o la opción de editar o borrar todos para que me funcione bien, ya que si pongo la llave de cerrar el for de las personas antes de cerrar el formulario solo me recoge el primer registro y si pongo la llave después de cerrar el formulario el botón de borrar varios se repite... alguien ha hecho algo parecido y ha encontrado una solución?

**Código jsp**

```
            <%
                if (session.getAttribute("ListaPersonas") != null) {
                    ArrayList<Persona> list = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("ListaPersonas");
                    if (list.size() > 0) {
                        Persona per;

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    per = list.get(i);
            %>   
            <form name="formusu" action="../Controlador.jsp" method="post">

                <input type="text" name="id_dep" value="<%out.print(per.getId_departamento());%>" hidden>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Dni </th>
                            <th scope="col">Nombre </th>
                            <th scope="col">Apellidos</th>
                            <th scope="col">Email</th>                                
                            <th scope="col">Departamento</th>
                            <th scope="col">Cambiar Departamento</th>
                            <th scope="col">Modificar</th>
                            <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="dni" value="<%out.print(per.getDni());%>" required></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="nombre" value="<%out.print(per.getNombre());%>" required>
                            <td><input type="text" name="apellidos" value="<%out.print(per.getApellidos());%>" required></td>
                            <td><input type="email" name="mail" value="<%out.print(per.getEmail());%>" required></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="nombredepar" value="<%out.print(per.getNombre_departamento());%>" readonly></td>

                            <%
                                if (session.getAttribute("departamentos") != null) {

                                    ArrayList<Departamento> listaDep = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("departamentos");
                                    if (listaDep.size() > 0) {
                            %>
                            <td>Elige Departamento: <SELECT NAME="departselecc">
                                    <%
                                        for (int j = 0; j < listaDep.size(); j++) {
                                    %>
                                    <!-- selected="<  %if(i==0){out.print("true");}%>"  -->
                                    <OPTION  VALUE="<%=listaDep.get(j).getId_departamento()%>"><%=listaDep.get(j).getNombre_departamento()%>
                                        <%
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        %> 
                                </SELECT>
                            </td>

                            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="modificarusudire" value="Modificar"></td>

                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="borrarvariasper" name="borrarvariasper" value="<%out.print(per.getDni());%>"/></td>
                        </tr>              
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <%
                    // } si cierro aquí el for, me funciona bien el botón de borrar varios con los checkbox, pero al editar las personas solo me recoge el primer registro
                %>        

                <div class="container text-center">
                    <br><input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" name="borrarpers" value="Eliminar Varios">
                </div>
            </form>
            <%
                        }
                    }
                }
            %>
```

Answer (score 1):

A ver, lo primero que tienes que tener claro es qué HTML quieres y entonces montar el JSP para que te lo genere.

En concreto, un único botón de "Borrar todos" (los seleccionados) tiene sentido porque después de hacer la petición vuelves a mostrar la tabla. Por eso simplemente tienes un checkbox para seleccionar los registros y un único botón.

Pero "Modificar todos" no tiene sentido porque normalmente las modificaciones las harás registro a registro, así que tienes un botón "Modificar" para cada registro.

Así que el `for` tiene que cerrarse antes del botón de "Borrar todos" para que solo haya uno.

El problema de que para modificar solo te coja el primero probablemente se deberá a que, en el botón de *submit* que usas para modificar, **no estás indicando de ninguna manera cuál es el registro que quieres modificar**. Una opción para solucionarlo es añadir el ID del registro al nombre del botón (p.ej. `name="modificar28"`), y en la lógica del servidor recuperar ese valor (p.ej. recorrer los `request.getParameterNames()` para encontrar el que empiece por `modificar`)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!! Al final conseguí hacer las dos cosas de esta manera: Dentro del formulario cree el checkbox haciendo referencia a otro formulario que está fuera, pasando el valor/es que necesito con el input form y el id del formulario que está fuera con el botón de borrar todos

<input form="borrarvariosusuarios" type="checkbox" name="borrarvariasper" value="<%out.print(per.getDni());%>">
<input form="borrarvariosusuarios" type="text" name="id_depar" value="<%out.print(per.getId_departamento());%>" hidden>

Comment: Dale el voto positivo y ponlo como respuesta, para que la gente quiera ayudarte en un futuro :)